# Two galleries with 50% parent's width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm developing an Android 3.1 tablet application.

In this application I will have a landscaped screen with two galleries and I want that those two galleries have 50% width.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frag_general_info_factory_table"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

[ ... ]

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/factGallery"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/wareHouseGallery"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

[ ... ]
</LinearLayout>
```

But it doesn't look well.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want them side by side horizontally, in which case you have the orientation of the LinearLayout wrong - it should be set to horizontal:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Comment: What a shame! Thank you for your answer.